# primefaces datatable show one button for entire column

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I am learning primefaces and I want to create a customized datatable. I am trying to create a column having only one commandButton/commandLink for the entire column.
Something like the below:

```
------------------------------
ID | Name | Year | Attachment |
------------------------------
01 | abcd | 2014 |            |
------------------
02 | decf | 2014 |  -------   |
------------------  |Attach|
03 | desf | 2014 |  -------   |
------------------
04 | ffgt | 2014 |            |
------------------------------
```

Like columnGroup do we have row group in primefaces. Or is there any better approach, kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known limitation of PrimeFaces `<p:dataTable>`, see [issue 1316](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=1316). `rowspan` and `colspan` do not work on the data cells of `<p:dataTable>`, they only work in the header and the footer of `<p:dataTable>`. I recently had this same issue and my solution using PrimeFaces was to use `<p:panelGrid>` then use the JSTL `<c:forEarch>` to loop through my data list to build the JSF components of a `<p:panelGrid>`. Example:

```
<p:panelGrid>
    <f:facet name="header">
        <p:row>
            <p:column>ID</p:column>
            <p:column>Name</p:column>
            <p:column>Attach</p:column>                            
         </p:row>
     </f:facet>
     <c:forEach items="#{myBean.data}" var="item" varStatus="index">  
         <p:row>
             <p:column><h:outputText value="#{item.id}" /></p:column>
             <p:column><h:outputText value="#{item.name}" /></p:column> 
             <p:column rowspan="4" rendered="#{index.count == 1}">
                 <h:outputText value="Button" />                                
             </p:column>                            
         </p:row>
     </c:forEach>
</p:panelGrid>
```

`rowspan` needs to match the number of items in your table.

Another solution is to use different JSF component library that supports this like [RichFaces](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_dataTable.html).

Comment: #Mark: the problem is i cant set the rowspan to 4 since the datatable is dynamic and it may show any number of rows based on search result

Comment: Set the size of you list as variable in your bean then output it as your rowspan `rowspan="#{myBean.sizeVariable}"`

Answer (score 0):

Use p:columnGroup with rowspan and colspan. following link may help you : 
http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/subTable.xhtml

Comment: `rowspan` and `colspan` only work in the header and footer of a PrimeFaces `<p:dataTable>`